# Adding text and image to footer

Tags: android, pdf, itext, drawable

```
try {
    java.io.InputStream ims = context1.getAssets().open("logo.png");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
        Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(new Chunk(image, 0, 0)), (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2, rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    return;
  } catch (BadElementException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am trying to add text and footer to page, but its not getting added. When i try the below, the text is shown, but **how to add text with image**.

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
            Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Some Text"), (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2, rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this: I'm surprised that the text shows up on the page, because assuming `rect` is the CropBox or MediaBox, adding something at position `rect.getBottom() - 18` means you're adding something outside the visual area of the page. (Of course: maybe my assumption that `rect` is the visible area may be wrong.)

As for your question: wrapping an `Image` inside a `Chunk` is fine if you use `document.add()`, but `document.add()` shouldn't be used in a page event, so you're probably better off with a different approach:

```
image.setAbsolutePosition((rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2, rect.getBottom() + 18);
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
canvas.addImage(image);
```

Also: could you check if the bytes provided by `stream.toByteArray()` represent a correct PNG file? Why do you compress the PNG at 100% quality? PNG is lossless (meaning the quality parameter will be ignored) and you're compressing one PNG to another PNG (and I don't understand why you'd do that).

Comment: Thanks it worked, but the size of the image is actually bigger... how can i give a size to an image.

Comment: There are different methods to do that: `scalePercent()`, `scaleAbsolute()`, etc... See http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html to get an overview.